# Loader appears while using the slider revolution

Tags: wordpress, loader, revolution-slider

I am using the slider revolution for my header, and I have a loader as the picture show when I have a carouseul of picture, between the transition of image (of even for the first image I have the loader, even when I use a fiber internet connection..). Do you know why and how to fix it ? At least how to apply a `display:none;` to it..

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try adding the following lines in *style.css*:

```
body .tp-loader.spinner1 {
  display: none;
  visibility: hidden;
}
```

Just change the *.spinner1* to the spinner number that is chosen in the Revolution Slider Settings.

**Update:**

The CSS for spinners are defined in the following location:

> plugins\revslider\rs-plugin\css\settings.css

As you can see, the spinner selectors all have `.tp-loader` class:

```
.tp-loader.spinner3{
...
}

.tp-loader.spinner5{
...
}
```

You could try to directly edit that settings.css file to see if it works.

Comment: Thanks, but I don't have anything call tp-loader when I inspecte my page...

Comment: Updated an answer.

Comment: Great! I found it! Does not work... it's even strange, I deleted the .gif icon from the asset file and it steal appears on my page...

Comment: On my version, there are two loader.gif files. One is in revslider/images, the other in evslider\rs-plugin\assets.

Comment: not mine, but in the .tp-loader ... when I see the code to upload the loader.gif, the path is inside the asset folder... anyway I uncomment all the code of the .tp-loader and even change the name of the loader.gif and I steal have it. I might be wrong somewhere for sure... Is it possible that the .gif is save inside the database or somewhere..? I modify it using my ftp..

Comment: If you are using a caching plugin this might cause it in which case, just delete the cache.

Answer (score 5):

Nowadays you can disable the spinner in the Slider Settings.

```
Layout & Visual > Spinner > Choose Spinner > Off
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/20135045)

Comment: It does not answer the question directly but provides a better solution to the problem of displaying the spinner in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

A simple way :

Slider Revolution → Module General Options → Spinner → None